# Difficulties populating a datagridview using an inner and outer for loop

Tags: vb.net

I have been looking for an answer to my problem but have not had any success unfortunately.

Firstly, here is my code:

```
    For x = 0 To (NumberOfRows - 1)
        For y = 0 To (NumberOfColumns - 1)
            DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value = TrimmedData(ArrayIndex)
            ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1
        Next
    Next
```

I have pre-set the number of columns and number of rows for the datagridview. The code above then cycles through two for loops in an attempt to populate the datagridview with data from a string array.

The problem is this line here:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value = TrimmedData(ArrayIndex)
```

It does not like it when I have the variables x and y (to determine the row and cell location) it works fine if I have just the variable x or just the variable y (with the other being a fixed number, for example this code is fine:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = TrimmedData(ArrayIndex)
```

Can any one lend a hand with how I can go about populating the data in a loop such as this?

Thankyou in advance.

EDIT, here is the full sub routine code:

```
    Private Sub ExtractData()
    Dim x As Decimal = 0
    Dim y As Decimal = 0
    Dim GetData As String = " StartOfData ,10,03,John Smith,8207176,a,c,d,b,d,a,b,d,c,b,Bill McBill,8109871,b,d,c,b,a,d,c,b,d,a,Amy Bunton,8212345,a,d,c,a,d,b,c,d,b,c, EndOfData "
    Dim TrimmedData() As String = GetData.Split(",")
    ' we need to find where the start of our data is (we do this because we may have recieved the same data, multiple times.)
    While TrimmedData(x) <> " StartOfData "
        x = x + 1
    End While
    Dim StartOfArrayData As Decimal = (x + 1)  'we have just found where StartOfData is written, so we add one to go to the actual start of our data
    Dim ArrayIndex As Decimal = StartOfArrayData
    Dim NumberOfColumns As Decimal = TrimmedData(ArrayIndex) + 2  'the first number in the array tells us how many questions there are in the exam. We add 2 because we need the student name and ID number
    ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1 ' now we are at the location where it tells us how many students there are.
    Dim NumberOfRows As Decimal = TrimmedData(ArrayIndex) + 1   ' we need to add one extra row because we have a certain number of rows for our student names + one extra for the headings
    ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = NumberOfColumns
    DataGridView1.RowCount = NumberOfRows
    ' and now we need to know where the end of our data is
    While TrimmedData(x) <> " EndOfData "
        x = x + 1
    End While
    Dim EndOfArrayData As Decimal = (x - 1)  'we have just found where EndOfData is written, so we minus one to go to the actual end of our data
    For x = 0 To (NumberOfRows - 1) ' we minus one because we are starting from 0 and not 1
        For y = 0 To (NumberOfColumns - 1)  ' we minus one because we are starting from 0 and not 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value = TrimmedData(ArrayIndex)
            ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

For background info - I am just starting out with making an exam system where students have a little wireless device with five buttons on them marked A B C D and SUBMIT, the students will have questions displayed on a data projector and they then press one of the A B C D buttons then submit. This answer will be sent to a microcontroller based device connected to the computer. Once all answers for all questions are submitted, it will send data serially to the computer program (I.E. this visual basic program I am working on) this data will be what is used in my code - at the moment I am just testing it by putting in some default data I.E.

```
Dim GetData As String = " StartOfData ,10,03,John Smith,8207176,a,c,d,b,d,a,b,d,c,b,Bill McBill,8109871,b,d,c,b,a,d,c,b,d,a,Amy Bunton,8212345,a,d,c,a,d,b,c,d,b,c, EndOfData "
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Whats the error message you receive?

Comment: Good point, it reads "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' can be called without a narrowing conversion."

Comment: And what Types are your columns... For instance... I've tested the above with three DataGridViewTextBoxColumn's... Albeit I had to add a new row in the inner loop to make it work ;-) I suspect maybe your using another column type somewhere maybe?

Comment: As a side question.... Can I ask what is contained in your "TrimmedData" array. I'm just wondering why you're populating your DataGridView this way?

Comment: To be honest I hadn't thought about the types for the columns. Do they default to textboxcolumns? for example, if I have this line of code DataGridView1.ColumnCount = NumberOfColumns will that default to textboxcolumns (because that is how I am creating the number of columns, likewise for the number of rows.)

Comment: I've not added columns or rows this way before, I normally specify columns directly using DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.HeaderText = "Testing"}), and rows using DataGridView1.Rows.Add(). However, your method should create TextBox columns by default. I've tried your method, and your code still works here. I perhaps need to see more of your code, and also some examples of what is contained in your TrimmedData array?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your other question now. I have updated the question to include the full sub routine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified;

```
Dim x As Decimal = 0
Dim y As Decimal = 0
```

Change that to;

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim y As Integer = 0
```

That will cure the Narrowing Conversion Error... However, you may need to look at your maths for fetching the data...

Comment: Yep, that did it! Many thanks for that PGallagher I can't thankyou enough :)

Comment: No problems at all! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest thing, all hard coded values.  If that works, gradually add in the dynamic stuff.

I have a guess that it may be in your array, try removing that and just use a string like "my data".  Also, do you have a header or footer in the gridview?  Remove those also for now. Sorry I entered this as an answer, but I can't make comments yet I think.